# PHP Custom Cache control only running once

Tags: php, cache-control

I'm setting this header using PHP on top of the document:

```
$editedonDate = "Fri, 08 Sep 2023 11:21:01 GMT";
header("Last-Modified: $editedonDate");
```

It's working fine the first time the site loads, once I press F5 to refresh the header is not loading again, just disappears.

Not idea why, anyone have an idea?

Thnaks!

Comment: Probably because the page got served from the cache?

Comment: Everything is being cached but the html, there is a Ngix cache in the server but if I disable it the problem persist. I was thinking any PHP setting that might be overtiming the headers?